# Non-latin letters shown bold in console when using ter-v16n font

Tags: linux, terminal, fonts, console, utf-8

I have to show various UTF-8 characters in my CentOS terminal and I'm playing with Terminus console fonts. If I'm using `ter-u16n` font I get properly drawn Cyrillic characters but available character set is limited to latin + cyrillic characters only. If I'm using `ter-v16n` font I get extended character set, however extended characters seems to be drawn bold (white) style by default. And thus I get inconsistent look for text with latin and non-latin characters. Here is two screenshots indicating the problem.

ter-u16n:

[image]

ter-v16n:

[image]

By the way, `ter-v16n` looks okay if I use `vga=` mode for Linux terminal. But is there a way to get correct representation of this font in standard Linux 80x25 console?

Comment: I vaguely remember that some fonts double the amount of available characters by re-using the 'bold' bit. Though they shouldn't be bold – I'm guessing that part is a bug.